# How to write an sql query in marketing cloud if field name contains a reserved string?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I'm using marketing cloud for sending various marketing communication. SFMC is integrated with sales cloud. I'm facing a problem while creating a data extension which contains a field name contains with FN. 
Actual field names goes something like - Prefix_abc_FN__c
When I write sql query system shows me error saying that FN is a reserved keyword and can't be used in query code.

Please let me know if there is any workaround possible without changing the field name in sales cloud?

sample sql query code -

```
select Prefix_field1, Prefix_field2, [Prefix_abc_FN__c] from Lead_Salesforce
```

Comment: Did you put the field in square brackets, such as `select a.[Prefix_abc_FN__c] ...`? Can we see an example query? Would you mind making an [edit] to show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Add the brackets as @sfdcfox and this will resolve the issue.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I tried brackets as suggested but unfortunately it didn't work. I've added sample query code in original question, please refer.